# Conducting interviews independently?

Tags: research-process, ethics, funding, interview

I'm an early career researcher who would like to conduct interviews for a research project on my own, and I was hoping to get some advice about whether this sort of thing is advisable.

I recently graduated and published my work in a peer reviewed journal, and I'm planning to continue my research through a PhD sometime in the next couple of years. However, I would also like to work a documentary type project related to my field of study, not for an academic audience but for the broader general public. 
I'm not currently affiliated with a university though, and have never conducted any interviews before (all my work so far has been archival), so I'm a little concerned about the ethics of my doing so without any kind of official backing. I'm not even sure if this is something I COULD get backing for as it would be a side project anyway.

Due to my area of research the window of opportunity for conducting interviews is rapidly closing, and I'm concerned about missing the chance. It wouldn't be feasible for me to wait until I'm more established, as the younger interviewees are already in their early 80s.

Would it be possible, and more importantly ethical for me to be doing this? Could I get funding for this? And should I be getting a university or other academics involved?

Comment: Many people with no qualifications do surveys / the web provides an avenue for many things... Is it ethical? Depends on who is looking. Will you get funding? Probably not, may well depend on how you present it or misrepresent it... Will other academics want to be involved? Good question...

Comment: It is not sufficient for your research to be ethical; it must also be approved in advance by an institutional ethics committee (that means not people on this website).

Comment: I think the specific research topic is central to answering this question, so I voted to close as off topic.  It's also too broad.

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist Thanks for your reply. I guess that was kind of my point. If it needs to be approved by an institution, I would probably need to be a part of said institution then?   I can provide more details if necessary. My field is history, so for this project I would be interviewing people and looking at their own experiences for analysis.

Comment: Ethical approval requirements differ between countries, same for procedures (some countries have national review boards where you could submit your proposal, but then, some of those might require you to be affiliated to a university...). Where are you located?

Answer (score 2):

There is a whole science about conducting and structuring interviews, and drawing scientific conclusions from it. If you are unfamiliar with it, then the interviews you will conduct are likely going to be poorly designed, and you may not be able to get out of them what you wanted, or with as much clarity as you hoped. That doesn't mean than it may not be entertaining, or of interest to the public, but it's probably still worthwhile reading up on how to best do interviews.

An entirely separate question is institutional backing. It is not unethical or wrong to conduct interviews as an individual -- journalists do it all the time. But you will need to have the approval of an Institutional Review Board (IRB) if you eventually want to use the interviews for scientific research you want to publish.

Comment: +1 I’m not aware of any reputable venue that’ll knowingly publish any human-based research without IRB approval.